# finding the time and space complexity of the following code

Tags: algorithm, analysis

what is the space and time complexity of following code and how

```
large(n) //n is +ve
{ 
    if(n<=1) 
        return n;

    sum=0;

    for(i=1 to n-1)
        sum=sum+large(i);

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have: `T(n <= 1) = O(1)` and `T(n) = T(n-1) + ... + T(1) + O(1)`.

Solving this recurrence, you get `T(n) = O(n!)`.

Besides, you can observe that `large(k)` is calculated `O(n)` times. Actually you can inscreasingly speed up the whole computation by noticing that this algorithm is a perfect candidate for dynamic programming!

Comment: Thank you Vakh! Can you also give space complexity for above code?

Comment: Space complexity is O(1)

Comment: how ? we at least get n level tree.Since among n-1 recursive calls T(n-1) goes at last to n level? Am I right? I somewhere came throgh similar question whose answer was O(n!)